# Splash Screen Progress bar not drawing

Tags: java, screen, awt, splash-screen, event-dispatch-thread

I'm trying to make my own progress bar, on my splash screen. Creating my splash screen was easy:

> java -splash:EaseMailMain.jpg Main.class
>   (From Eclipse)

The first line of my main method calls this:

```
new Thread(new Splash()).start();
```

And this is the splash class:

```
    public class Splash implements Runnable {
    public volatile static int percent = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Start");
        final SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
        if (splash == null) {
            System.out.println("SplashScreen.getSplashScreen() returned null");
            return;
        }
        Graphics2D g = splash.createGraphics();
        if (g == null) {
            System.out.println("g is null");
            return;
        }
        int height = splash.getSize().height;
        int width = splash.getSize().width;
        //g.drawOval(0, 0, 100, 100);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawRect(0, height-50, width, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        while(percent <= 100) {
            System.out.println((width*percent)/100);
            g.drawRect(0, height-50, (int)((width*percent)/100), 50);
            percent += 1;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors, but I do get a small box underneath it:

[image: The image with a rectangle below.]

If I change the drawRects to (0, 0, width, height) it makes no difference.

I've tried invoking on the swing EDT with:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait((new Splash()));
```

But nothing happens.

Can anyone see the problem? Or know how to fix it?

Comment: I am not able to try this (thus the comment), but I would be careful with the line: `(width * percent) / 100` since these are all operations on integers.

Comment: That's a valid point, I'll cast the 100 to double.

Comment: You can just write 100.0.

Comment: @sdasdadas Casting back to an `int` will truncate anyway...

Comment: @Code-Guru: The thing I was worried about is that integer / integer does not return what some programmers expect it to return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [`SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29) when updating the GUI from a different thread.

Please see the Chapter [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) which explains the reasons behind this.

The [SplashScreen Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) from the Tutorial does the `Thread.sleep` inside the Swing thread. This is fine, too if you do not need any other GUI refresh while the SplashScreen is showing. Your loading code however should happen in a different thread.

I would recommend adding a `setPercent` setter to your class which creates a `Runnable` to update the GUI via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`. That way you do not even need to poll the `percent` variable and the `SwingThread` is free to render other UI stuff, too.

Comment: Oh forgot to add that bit, I'd already tested that, it makes no difference.

Comment: @Adude11 From you example code, no you didn't, or at least, no you didn't do it right...I've extended on bikeshedder's recommendations (+1) and tried to expand on the reasons why you're having trouble.  If you find it useful, I would appropriate a up-vote, but you should give credit to bikeshedder for identifying the problem (an mark their answer as correct).

Answer (score 3):

Bikeshedder is right (+1), you're blocking the EDT.

```
while(percent <= 100) {
    System.out.println((width*percent)/100);
    g.drawRect(0, height-50, (int)((width*percent)/100), 50);
    percent += 1;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Using `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait((new Splash()));` is placing the `Runnable` onto the Event Queue, meaning when you enter your `while` loop and `Thread.sleep`, you're preventing the Event Queue from dispatching any new events, including repaint requests

You should be using something like a `SwingWorker` to perform your actually loading (in a background thread), publishing the progress results, which the splash screen can the display....

[image]

```
public class TestSplashScreen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestSplashScreen();
    }

    public TestSplashScreen() {
        SplashScreenWorker worker = new SplashScreenWorker();
        worker.execute();
        try {
            worker.get();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("All Done...");
//        Launch main application...
//        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...);
    }

    public class SplashScreenWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Float> {

        private SplashScreen splash;

        public SplashScreenWorker() {
            splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
            if (splash == null) {
                System.out.println("SplashScreen.getSplashScreen() returned null");
                return;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Float> chunks) {
            Graphics2D g = splash.createGraphics();
            if (g == null) {
                System.out.println("g is null");
                return;
            }
            float progress = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
            int height = splash.getSize().height;
            int width = splash.getSize().width;
            g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            g.setPaintMode();
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawRect(0, height - 50, width, 50);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            int y = height - 50;
            g.fillRect(0, y, (int) (width * progress), 50);
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            String text = "Loading Microsoft Windows..." + NumberFormat.getPercentInstance().format(progress);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString(text, (width - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2, y + ((50 - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent());
            g.dispose();
            splash.update();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int value = 0; value < 1000; value++) {

                float progress = value / 1000f;
                publish(progress);
                Thread.sleep(25);

            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```